# How to verify an IP address is DNSSEC-ed with dnspython?

Tags: dns, dnspython, dnssec

I sent recursive DNS queries to root name servers, TLD servers, and authoritive servers for `stanford.edu`.

> Root response:

[image]

> TLD response:

[image]

> Authority response:

[image]

At all 3 levels, I could see that DNSSEC is supported. How could I use dnspython and information in the responsed messages to validate that the resposed messages are secured and legitimate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137036/programmatically-check-if-domains-are-dnssec-protected - May be this can help.

Comment: Thank you but that code is actually not working.